# In-App Review Popup window not showing again once "Not Now" is pressed

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play-services, google-developers-console

This below code returns successful even when user has cancelled before submitting review and popup window for review does not showing up again. (Shows only for 1st time)

- How can re-launch the In-App Review popup when user has not submitted ?

  ```
     Task <ReviewInfo> request = reviewManager.requestReviewFlow();
         request.addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
           if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            // Getting the ReviewInfo object
            ReviewInfo reviewInfo = task.getResult();

            Task <Void> flow = reviewManager.launchReviewFlow(this, reviewInfo);
            flow.addOnCompleteListener(task1 -> {
                // The flow has finished. The API does not indicate whether the user
                // reviewed or not, or even whether the review dialog was shown.
            });
        }
    });
  ```

Answer (score 1):

To provide a great user experience, Google Play enforces a time-bound quota on how often a user can be shown the review dialog. Because of this quota, calling the launchReviewFlow method more than once during a short period of time (for example, less than a month) might not always display a dialog.

Note: The specific value of the quota is an implementation detail, and it can be changed by Google Play without any notice.

Because the quota is subject to change, it's important to apply your own logic and target the best possible moment to request a review. For example, you should not have a call-to-action option (such as a button) to trigger the API, as a user might have already hit their quota and the flow won’t be shown, presenting a broken experience to the user. For this use case, redirect the user to the Play Store instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is by the design of that dialogue.

Just for the record and comparison here is how similar dialogue works on iOS/macOS. Your code is considered only as a request to display the dialogue. The operating system may or may not show it. It is never shown to user more than twice a year. The operating system protects users from bad developers who want to spam them according to their needs.

It is very similar on Google Play though the rules a bit less strict, but it is not as crazy as that you can display the dialogue twice in the same day.